# Equivalence Relations Topic: Prime Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let us consider the relation $\sim$ defined upon $ℕ$ as follows: \begin{align} x \sim y \iff x \text{ and } y \text{ are both prime.} \end{align}

What I cannot grasp is the fact that this relation is symmetric and transitive but not reflexive? I asked my lecturer and he gave me the example of reflexivity as in, if we considered $x \sim x$ and took $x$ to be $4,$ we know that $4$ is not prime and, therefore, $4$ is not related to $4.$

So why is it that, if we took any number for $x$ and $y,$ the relation is still symmetric and transitive? I seriously cannot understand this and it's hurting my head.

Any clarification would be sincerely appreciated.

Kindest regards

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are both primes, then $y $ and $x$ are both primes. - If $x$ and $y$ are primes, and $y$ and $z$ are primes, then $x$ and $z$ are primes. - However, as $x=4$ shows: For arbitrary $x$ it need not be the case that both $x$ and $x$ are prime

Comment: One should say that a relation is reflexive on some specified set; not just that it's reflexive. This relation is reflexive on the set of prime numbers; it is not reflexive on $\mathbb N. \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

If $x\sim y$ then it means both $x,y$ are prime. But of course this implies that both $y,x$ are prime (as these are the same numbers, we just wrote them in different order), and so $y\sim x$ by definition. So the relation is symmetric.

As for transitive, suppose $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$. Then $x,y$ are both prime and $y,z$ are both prime. It follows that $x,z$ are both prime, and so $x\sim z$.

Comment: Alright that makes more sense. But why do we not do that for reflexivity? Why don't we say that if x $\sim$ x, then x is prime?

Comment: $x\sim x$ indeed implies that $x$ is prime, this is true. However, by definition reflexivity means that we have $x\sim x$ for every $x$ in our set. In our example this is not the case, because $4$ is not a prime number, and thus we don't have $4\sim 4$. So the relation is not reflexive.